# Object's properties undefined

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

Playing around with the sample network of car auction.
I am not sure why the "Offer" transaction works as it shows all the properties, but the "AmendOffer" transaction shows properties start with $ as undefined?

Is there a way to translate transaction from "AmendOffer" to "Offer", I tried to make a copy of "AmendOffer" and then delete the property "oldTransactionID" on the copied one to make it the same as "Offer" transaction.

```
abstract transaction OfferTrans {
  o Double bidPrice
  --> VehicleListing listing
  --> Member member
}

transaction Offer extends OfferTrans {
}

transaction AmendOffer extends OfferTrans {
  o String oldTransactionID
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have TP functions to match your transactions and using your model, in Composer Playground, you will get the transactions (you modeled) as shown below - in Historian.

```
{
 "$class": "org.acme.vehicle.auction.Offer",
 "bidPrice": 10,
 "listing": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.VehicleListing#L1",
 "member": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.Member#1",
 "transactionId": "d133abab-cd96-4f15-ac06-ca7a065f2e84",
 "timestamp": "2018-06-04T10:38:17.042Z"
}

{
 "$class": "org.acme.vehicle.auction.AmendOffer",
 "oldTransactionID": "3333",  // whatever
 "bidPrice": 0,
 "listing": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.VehicleListing#L1",
 "member": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.Member#1",
 "transactionId": "3576a2f2-6264-4490-9b79-ef0d612ed07a",
 "timestamp": "2018-06-04T10:37:50.854Z"
}
```

If you DON'T want to store 'oldTransactionId' as a mandatory field - simply make it optional in your model file.

```
transaction AmendOffer extends OfferTrans {
  o String oldTransactionID optional
}
```

eg the following would then work as an `AmendOffer`transaction

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.vehicle.auction.AmendOffer",
  "bidPrice": 10,
  "listing": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.VehicleListing#L1",
  "member": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.auction.Member#1"
}
```

If you wanted to update the `Offers[]` array in that sample network (as it exists today) you would obviously provide the appropriate transaction code to do so.

Comment: Thanks for replying! In the case when there is an amendment to an order, I would like to save the amendment as an "Offer" transaction - so the oldTransactionID should not be saved. I had been trying to deep copy the passed in transaction and delete the property "oldTransactionID", I probably missed something in the deep copy process and getting undefined values.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Seems to me, you just need to make the property `optional`

Comment: Thanks Paul! I get your point, but I do want to pass the oldTransactionId at all time for the AmendOffer transactions. Is there a way to convert this to an Offer transaction. Lets say the original transaction is not there to be amended, instead I would like to place a new Offer transaction.

Comment: This is a blockchain (with a deployed business network/smart contract). Transactions are added to a LEDGER. A LEDGER is a history/chronology of transactions that update the state of assets or participants (in a business network), to get to a world state (for an asset/participant) that holds the last known committed value for any given key - an indexed view into the chain’s transaction log (with its history of Offers or AmendOffers). You don't 'amend' a transaction - that's the whole point of a blockchain. Now to your question: (contd)

Comment: I think you mean an amendment to an "offer" (not order). You can/could have one 'Offer' transaction class (IMO) and save the history of Offer transaction IDs (the transactions themselves are already in the ledger) and offer amounts etc in an auctionable asset if you wish. Its pretty easy to see then what 'transaction' amended a previous transaction (if at all) - on the asset. I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What I tried to do defeat the purpose of a Ledger, bear in mind that this is a blockchain. I over thought after all. Thanks for being patient!